# CSS, Responsive Design, Image not resizing

Tags: html, css

I have a header image that stopped resizing after I placed it in a CSS wrapper.  I specified the width of the wrapper, b/c I want the navigation to the right to be directly above the white space area below - flushed to the right.

How can I set the width of the wrapper in which I place an image but maintain the responsiveness (image responds to resizing)?

HERE's the URL; http://www.insidemarketblog.com/

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="menu_control">≡ Menu</span>
<ul class="nav"><li class="page_item page-item-35"><a href="http://www.insidemarketblog.com/us/">ABOUT US</a></li></ul>
        <h1 id="site_title"><a href="http://www.insidemarketblog.com"><img id="thesis_logo_image" src="http://www.insidemarketblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/logo_header1.png" alt="Inside Market Strategy" width="400" height="87" title="click to go home" />
</a></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the image flex too:

```
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that in Firebug in the CSS: img and site_title img, but to no avail.  All it does is make the logo image fill up the entire wrapper, but doesn't resize when I resize the window.  Am I implementing it incorrectly?

Comment: Shouldn't that be max-width?

Comment: @user3117275 even with max-width, it will not be responsive until the .wrap width change.  what is happening here is the image is inside a `.wrap` container with a fixed width, so no mater you re-size the window, the image will have no effect because it will never reach its father width.  you should change your wrap width first to be responsive, please see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/59LKP/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two issues here:

1st, Your `.wrap` is 1000px in width.  please make it 100%
2nd, your img css should have a max-width: 400px; and width:100%

This way you will have your img exactly the way you want it.

Here is the css:

```
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: auto;
}
```

**See it in Action:** http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/59LKP/